# Calling topLayoutGuide breaks scrolling altogether?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I am having weird issues with the `topLayoutGuide` method, which I have to use in a situation where `setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:` doesn't work. To narrow down the cause of the problem, I've created the following minimal example, which just sets up a basic table view for testing:

1. Set up a new iOS Single View application in Xcode.
2. Paste the following code in ViewController.m's implementation:

   ```
   @implementation ViewController

   - (void)loadView
   {
       [self setTableView:[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain]];
   }

   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       [self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO]; // [*]
   }

   - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
   {
       UITableView *tableView = [self tableView];

       UIEdgeInsets insets = [tableView contentInset];
       // insets.top = [[self topLayoutGuide] length]; // [1]
       // insets.top = 100;                            // [2]

       [tableView setContentInset:insets];
       [tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:insets];
   }

   #pragma mark - Table view data source

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
       return 100;
   }

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

       if (cell == nil) {
           cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
       }

       [[cell textLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [indexPath row]]];

       return cell;
   }

   @end
   ```

The issues that I'm having are these:

1. If I uncomment the line marked with `[1]`, the correct inset is applied, but scrolling the table view no longer works. When I try to scroll, the table just bounces back to the initial scroll position after I release my finger. This behaviour is also triggered by a plain call to `[self topLayoutGuide]`, without assigning the result to anything.
2. If I uncomment line `[2]` *instead* of `[1]`, scrolling works. The inset of 100 pt is applied as well. But now the initial scrolling position is automatically adjusted so that the content underlaps the status bar.

(`[*]`: This really only seems to do anything in combination with a containing navigation controller. I doesn't seem to make a difference in this example, but I want to disable any automatic behaviour just to be sure.)

Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong? I'm really at a loss here.

Comment: I just found out that the call to `[self topLayoutGuide]` causes the table view's `contentSize` property to change from the correct value to `{0, 0}`. No idea why this is happening, though …

Comment: probably a bug, have that one, too.

Comment: Same thing here. This is incredibly frustrating. Feels like good old iOS 3.0 times.

Answer (score 11):

This is definitely a bug in iOS 7 (doesn't appear to be fixed in 7.1) but seems to only affect `UITableViewControllers`. I switched over to using a `UIViewController` with an embedded `UITableView` since I am not using static cells and don't need any of the 'magic' that a `UITableViewController` gives you.

Once I wired up the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` manually I was able to start using `self.topLayoutGuide` without messing up the tableView's contentSize.

This was an acceptable workaround for me until Apple fixes the bug.

Answer (score 2):

Same thing to me, instead of getting the topLayoutGuide, try this:

```
CGFloat topOffset = CGRectGetMaxY(self.refController.navigationController.navigationBar.frame);
```