# UITableView contentSize zero after [UIViewController updateViewConstraints] is called

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, autolayout

In the process of converting a project to use Auto-Layout, I'm dealing with an issue where a `UITableView` 's `contentSize` is initially set correctly, but after the parent `UITableViewController`'s `-updateViewConstraints` is called, the `contentSize` is zero.

```
App[36457:60b] -- viewWillAppear in (KRTestTableViewController) Called!

App[36457:60b] -- viewWillLayoutSubviews (KRTestTableViewController): content size = (320.0, 611.0), inset=(64.0, 93.0), offset=(-64.0), layout guides=(64.0, 93.0)
App[36457:60b] -- viewDidLayoutSubviews  (KRTestTableViewController): content size = (320.0, 611.0), inset=(64.0, 93.0), offset=(-64.0), layout guides=(64.0, 93.0)
App[36457:60b] **** updateConstraints called in (KRTestTableViewCell)
App[36457:60b] **** updateViewConstraints called in (KRTestTableViewController). content size height=(611.0), contentOffset = -64.0, inset=(64.0, 93.0)
App[36457:60b] before calling [super updateViewConstraints], KRTestTableViewController.view.needsUpdateConstraints = 1
App[36457:60b] after  calling [super updateViewConstraints], KRTestTableViewController.view.needsUpdateConstraints = 0
App[36457:60b] -- viewWillLayoutSubviews (KRTestTableViewController): content size = (0.0, 0.0), inset=(64.0, 93.0), offset=(-64.0), layout guides=(64.0, 93.0)
App[36457:60b] -- viewDidLayoutSubviews  (KRTestTableViewController): content size = (0.0, 0.0), inset=(64.0, 93.0), offset=(-64.0), layout guides=(64.0, 93.0)

App[36457:60b] -- viewDidAppear in (KRTestTableViewController) Called!
```

I have narrowed the issue down to the content size being set to zero after updating constraints.
Any ideas on what could be causing this or how to resolve it?
Is this the normal expected sequence: view layout, then updating constraints, and view layout again?

Comment: For reasons yet unknown, calling a `[tableView begin/endUpdates]` or an empty `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:nil ...]` in `-viewDidAppear` triggers `-viewWill/DidLayoutSubviews` in the view controller, and subsequently produces a correct `-contentSize`. Putting it in `-viewWillAppear` instead doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the root reason! There is a bug with `topLayoutGuide` and `UITableViewController`, where if you call `topLayoutGuide`, the `contentSize` of the `UITableView` will be set to zero! Hours of bug hunting was caused by a quite unnecessary debug log statement outputting the value of `topLayoutGuide` =_+

My previous comment on calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:nil ...` to fix `contentSize` still does correct the `contentSize`. I have placed it (with a zero-check) inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in case the need for `topLayoutGuide` arises.

See same issue here: [Calling topLayoutGuide breaks scrolling altogether?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595479/calling-toplayoutguide-breaks-scrolling-altogether)